# Using freemarker With Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, freemarker

sorry if the question seems a bit stupid, I am discovering Maven and Freemarker for a project and while going through Freemarker's doc I saw the xml code to put in the pom.xml file to include freemarker as a dependcy in the project, an I made a small test Class to try and get my first output file but I get errors saying that diffferent exceptio types were unhandled. Should I be doing anything else to work with freemarker?

my pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Training</groupId>
  <artifactId>Proj-1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.32</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
</project>
```

my main java code

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateExceptionHandler;
import freemarker.template.Version;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          // 1. Configure FreeMarker
        //
        // You should do this ONLY ONCE, when your application starts,
        // then reuse the same Configuration object elsewhere.

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

        // Where do we load the templates from:
        cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(MainTest.class, "src/templates");

        // Some other recommended settings:
        cfg.setIncompatibleImprovements(new Version(2, 3, 20));
        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        cfg.setLocale(Locale.US);
        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);

        // 2. Process template(s)
        //
        // You will do this for several times in typical applications.

        // 2.1. Prepare the template input:

        Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        input.put("title", "Vogella example");

        input.put("exampleObject", new ValueExampleObject("Java object", "me"));

        List<ValueExampleObject> systems = new ArrayList<ValueExampleObject>();
        systems.add(new ValueExampleObject("Android", "Google"));
        systems.add(new ValueExampleObject("iOS States", "Apple"));
        systems.add(new ValueExampleObject("Ubuntu", "Canonical"));
        systems.add(new ValueExampleObject("Windows7", "Microsoft"));
        input.put("systems", systems);

        // 2.2. Get the template

        Template template = cfg.getTemplate("helloworld.ftl");

        // 2.3. Generate the output

        // Write output to the console
        Writer consoleWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
        template.process(input, consoleWriter);

        // For the sake of example, also write output into a file:
        Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("output.html"));
        try {
            template.process(input, fileWriter);
        } finally {
            fileWriter.close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help :)

edit:
Here's what the console returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Unhandled exception type TemplateNotFoundException
    Unhandled exception type MalformedTemplateNameException
    Unhandled exception type ParseException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type TemplateException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type TemplateException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
```

Comment: You should be handling or rethrowing whatever exceptions the methods you call throw in the code you posted. So check the relevant documentation, and if this comment makes no sense to you, read on Exceptions, for example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: Don't you use Eclipse or IntellIiJ? They should tell you about the problems.

Comment: I use Eclipse but the only thing I Iget is the console messgae showed in the post.